# Wordpress Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm using this Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin to see my rewrite rules if there is any wrong in my code and i have one :

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '/?([^/]+(?<!categories))/([^/]+)/?$',//preg_quote('/?([^/]+(?<!categories))/([^/]+)/?$')
    'index.php?list-item=$matches[2]&post_type=list-item',
    'top'
);
```

I have two questions :

1- This code works well with all content types that i have put doesn't work with category page it gives me error ** preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'c' **

2- How to change the category page to get from custom content type not from post type.

Comment: Your first question is easy, you need to escape the forward slashes or change the delimiters. Your second one is unclear and you don't show how you tried to solve it.

Comment: @HamZa the second one i added this code in the category.php

`<?php
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'list' ) );
query_posts( $args );
?>`

Comment: I still have the same error here is reg that i'm using `\/(?!category)[^\/]+\/([^\/]+\/?){1}$` work's fine outside Wordpress why it doesn't work with add_rewrite_rule function i don't know ?

Comment: What error do you get ? Also you should know that 99.999999% of your problems has already occured many times and that there is already a solution for it. Have you searched the error ? Have you followed a tutorial on how to do what you want or are you just trying ... ?

Comment: that the error i get `Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier 'c' in C:\wamp\www\ProjectLap\wp-content\plugins\rewrite-rules-inspector\rewrite-rules-inspector.php on line 165`

and yes i searched about this problem and they all that i have to escape the special chars and i did put when i do that the code doesn't work at all

Comment: Can you please enter [the regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767) ?